# Trouble connecting to MySQL Zend Framework

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-studio

I'm trying to set up an application using the Zend Framework but the problem i'm getting is as soon as i add the following line in the `application.ini` the default home page that is created by the zend tool throws a fatal error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception' with
>   message 'Configuration array must have a key for 'password' for login
>   credentials' in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php:295
>   Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(183):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->_checkRequiredOptions(Array) #1
>   C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Db.php(270):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->__construct(Array) #2
>   C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Application\Resource\Db.php(142):
>   Zend_Db::factory('PDO_MYSQL', Array) #3
>   C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Application\Resource\Db.php(154):
>   Zend_Application_Resource_Db->getDbAdapter() #4
>   C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php(683):
>   Zend_Application_Resource_Db->init() #5
>   C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php(626):
>   Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource('db')
>
> ## 6 C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php(586):
>
> Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap(NULL) #7
>   C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Ap in
>   C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php on line 295

```
resources.db.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
resources.db.params.host = localhost
resources.db.params.dbname = codenamesnm
```

i'm using xampp with windows 7 Any idea what is wrong

Comment: Does your application.ini have the `phpSettings.display_startup_errors` and `phpSettings.display_errors`directives set to "**1**"?

Comment: @Liyali i tried setting them to `1` but nothing appeared the db settings i have set are under `[production]`

Comment: What about `resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions`?

Comment: just a moment let me chk

Comment: there it is an error has been spitted out i'm gonna update the question

Comment: @Liyali as per the error it seems i have to specify the password field but with xampp phpmyadmin i dont have a password field

Comment: @Liyali problem solved please post your comments as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not omit these lines:

```
resources.db.params.username = rob
resources.db.params.password = 123456
```

set them to `"root"` or `""` if necessary, but let them into your *application.ini*.